# Biometria em base64 gerando códigos diferentes para uma mesma digital

Tags: java, base64

Estou tendo problemas com a codificação de digitais (biometrias) em `base64` para passagem de parâmetro via `http`. O problema é que a cada captura da mesma digital são gerados códigos diferentes, desta forma não dá para comparar com as que estão cadastradas na base que tem relação um para um (um usuário, uma digital). Só a nível de esclarecimento, não posso usar a classe `Base64` nativa do `Java 8`, pois os clientes devem rodar `Java 7`, para evitar a burocratização pela segurança do `Java 8`. Então, para isso eu só via até agora duas alternativas, a primeira usando o método abaixo:

```
BaseEncoding.base64().encode(digital);
```

e, a segunda com:

```
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(digital);
```

mas em nenhum dos casos geram códigos iguais para uma mesma digital. Obrigado pela ajuda que me for prestado.

Comment: a variável  `digital` é de que tipo?

Answer (score 2):

Como o Roberto Fagundes falou, com esse tipo de biometria nós trabalhamos por aproximação.

Se você pegar qualquer celular com reconhecimento de digital, ele pede para você inserir a digital de cada dedo de cinco a dez vezes. Quando você vai se cadastrar em um plano de saúde ou qualquer outra coisa geralmente se capturam várias amostras também.

Você precisa guardar uma quantidade de amostras do usuário, e quando receber um input deve buscar as digitais que forem mais próximas na base de dados. Você autentica o usuário se conseguir um match arbitrariamente alto com alguma digital específica que esteja presente em sua base de dados.

Finalmente:

> (...)os clientes devem rodar java 7, para evitar a burocratização pela segurança do java 8(...)

Se você vai evitar uma versão do Framework porque ele é mais seguro, sua aplicação está exposta a falhas de segurança conhecidas. Chega a ser irônico que você esteja tentando manter o sistema seguro através de digitais (que são falsificáveis), mas não esteja utilizando a versão mais atual do Java. Isso é tão perigoso quanto brincar de paintball com armas de fogo.

Answer (score 1):

Trabalhar com biometria você não pode trabalhar por `igualdade`, a comparação deve ser feita por `aproximação`, até porque, a pessoa raramente vai colocar o dedo na mesma posição.

Talvez, o recomendado seja você procurar algum leitor que contenha um `SDK` para `JAVA`.

Comment: Então nesse caso devo criar uma outra tabela só com as digitais e criar uma relação tipo (1 funcionário para N digitais)? Faz sentido, mas o estranho é que já funciona localmente quando a digital recém captada pelo leitor é comparada com uma base local primeiramente, só não encontra quando realmente o funcionário não está nessa base local é quando eu tenho que ir buscar no server, e é ai que tá o gargalo. Mas obrigado pelo conhecimento compartilhado.